# Reuse Sets Created(Java)

Tags: java, csv

I am currently working on a task where I am struggling with creating multiple values against a single set which i have created:

```
package lacsp.portal.backing.oracle.webcenter.portalapp.pages;

import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class CSVUtilsExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomSets = rand.nextInt(100000) + 1;
    int val = 1;
    final DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0000");
    String csvFile = "C:/work/tableOutput.csv";
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
    CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, Arrays.asList("SET_ID", "INT_VALUE"));
    // Will loop whilst val is less than the random sets generated 
    while (val <= randomSets) {
        int random = rand.nextInt(100000) + 1;
        List<Orders> orders =
            Arrays.asList(new Orders("S" + decimalFormat.format(val),
                                     new Integer(random)));
        for (Orders o : orders) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(o.getSET_ID());
            list.add(o.getINT_VALUE().toString());
            CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list);

            //try custom separator and quote.
            //CSVUtils.writeLine(writer, list, '|', '\"');

        }
        val++;
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

}


}
```

The code above will write out to a .csv file and will assign a random INT_VALUE to a SET_ID which is created, Currently there is only 1 INT_VALUE for every SET_ID however my question is how could I make it so that a random number of INT_VALUES are assigned to a single SET_ID?

E.G

### #SET_ID# #INT_VALUE#

### S0001

```
    55
    712
    379
    1
    1111
```

---

### S0002

```
    76  
    985
```

---

### S0003

```
    1
    1059
    23
    22
    77
```

............

Orders.Java

```
package lacsp.portal.backing.oracle.webcenter.portalapp.pages;

public class Orders {

private String SET_ID;
private Integer INT_VALUE;

public Orders(String SET_ID, Integer INT_VALUE) {
    this.SET_ID = SET_ID;
    this.INT_VALUE = INT_VALUE;

}

public void setSET_ID(String SET_ID) {
    this.SET_ID = SET_ID;
}

public String getSET_ID() {
    return SET_ID;
}

public void setINT_VALUE(Integer INT_VALUE) {
    this.INT_VALUE = INT_VALUE;
}

public Integer getINT_VALUE() {
    return INT_VALUE;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Orders` class? At least the constructor for it.

Comment: Apologies should have added that also

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
List<Orders> orders =
        Arrays.asList(new Orders("S" + decimalFormat.format(val),
                                 new Integer(random)));
```

You create a list with only 1 item. I think you want to create a random number of items, each with random ids:

```
// Create an empty list
List<Orders> orders = new ArrayList<>();
// Single set id for all items
String setId = "S" + decimalFormat.format(val);
// Create a bunch of orders
int numOrders = rand.nextInt(100);
for (int i = 0; i < numOrders; i++) {
    // Create a new Order and add it to the list
    orders.add(new Orders(setId, rand.nextInt(10000) + 1));
}
```

Also, you name the class `Orders` but it really should be `Order` as it is just a single order.

Comment: That worked a treat thank you very much Johnny it returned the results I expected :)